# Is there a way to fix my two dimensional array problem

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

How can I find the total sum for each two dimensional array row? I'm completely stuck...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [][] grid = new int [10][10];

    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*99);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            System.out.print("1.");
            System.out.printf("%5d ", grid[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


}
```

My current output is: 
[image: Output]

How can I show the total sum for each row in the end of the row and show column numbers

Comment: "_But it should show the total sum_" Where in your code did you think addition was being done?

Comment: @takendarkk I don't know how to implement it

Comment: Why did you expect `print("1.")` to print a column number? Perhaps printing the value of `j` (or maybe `j + 1`) would be more appropriate, don't you think?

Comment: *"How can I show the total sum for each row"* By adding the values of the row, and printing the result. Which part is stopping you? Add values? Print result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sum of a row, this should do. In a similar way within the i loop, if you need to count the column as well;

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int jSum = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            jSum += grid[i][j];
            System.out.print("1.");
            System.out.printf("%5d ", grid[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.printf(" %5d", jSum);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

On the column numbering:
Either you just pust put a static print in the beginning (like print "1  2  3  4..."), or you put the following with the j loop:

```
if (i == 0) System.out.printf("%5d  ", j); // only prints in first loop / row - print 1,2,3,4,5....
```